# Is it possible to create a table using sql loader?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-loader

Like the question says, I would like to know if is possible to create a table from sql loader, the situation is, I have a .xls with 3 columns, where one column is the name of the column I have to create, another one the type it must be and the other one the length, there are almost 300, doing that manually would be very tedious, thanks for reading, I will be waiting for any answer, if it isnt possible, I would be very thankful for possible altenatives I could use

Comment: So it is ultimately one table with ~300 columns you need to create? (so many columns is often a red flag for table design, but that is beside the point). Are you familiar with any scripting languages? In many programming languages, it would be fairly easy to read a CSV file exported from the XLS and use it to create a `CREATE TABLE` statement meeting your requirements. I know of no tool to do it directly though.

Comment: I will admit in the past I have also done things like use the `CONCATENATE()` function in Excel to combine columns into a string that works as SQL, then copy/pasting out of it.